# Elastic APM Java Agent or Opentelemetry java agent?: Goal - Get metric-,trace- and logdata

Tags: java, elasticsearch, trace, agent, otel

does anyone have experience with the data ingestion via opentelemetry java agent and the elastic apm jva agent?

Are there differences in the dataquality of the output? Which is the best agent?

Best regards

Comment: Both options collect high-quality data. However, `OpenTelemetry` Java agent might be good choice if you need to collect data from big sources or if you want data in specific format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of features not available in OpenTelemetry (at least for now) like [profiling](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/java/1.x/config-profiling.html) that you have in the APM agent. There are also a few things with OTel that aren't yet supported by the APM server like JSON encoded messages for OTLP/HTTP or some calculations in the UI that depend on specific agent features, see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/guide/current/open-telemetry-known-limitations.html.

Unless you need those features, I would go with the OTel agent which is becoming pretty much the standard for tracing.
The supported features will really depend on the libraries and frameworks you want to use; that's hard to answer in general.